# MySQL sum() on different group bys

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have a query over two tables. I need to get two sums. I do a `group by` so the `sum()` works correctly.

```
SELECT sum(a.x), sum(b.y) FROM a,b GROUP BY a.n where a.n=b.m
```

So far this works well, but the problem is i need to group them differently for the second sum (`sum(b.y)`), than for the first sum (`sum(a.x)`).

The real query is somewhat more complex but this is my main problem.

This is what i actually try to select `sum(stock.amount) - if( sold.amount IS NULL , 0, sum( sold.amount ) )`

How can I solve that in one query?

Comment: How is table a and b connected ? is it one to many relation ? many to many ?

Comment: table relation is one to many

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing `if( sold.amount IS NULL , 0, sum( sold.amount ) )`? Group functions ignore nulls.

Comment: group yes, but mysql will return an error if you try to calucate 3-NULL, since NULL means no matching entries, it's the same as 0 in this case, so i simply check if it's null and pass 0 if it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are not writing down the tables I am gonna make a wild guess and assume the tables are like :

**stock** : id, item_id, amount
**sold** : id, item_id, amount

then again I assume that you need the stock_in_total, sold_total, left_total counts

```
SELECT 
  stock_sums.item_id, 
  stock_sums.st_sum as stock_in_total,
  COALESCE(sold_sums.so_sum,0) as sold_total,
  (stock_sums.st_sum - COALESCE(sold_sums.so_sum,0)) as left_total
FROM (
  SELECT stock.item_id as item_id, SUM(stock.amount) as st_sum 
  FROM stock 
  GROUP BY item_id
) as stock_sums 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT sold.item_id as item_id, SUM(sold.amount) as so_sum 
  FROM sold
  GROUP by item_id
) as sold_sums ON stock_sums.item_id = sold_sums.item_id
```

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.  I assume that Stock is the main table, with an ID and an amount, and that Sold maps to Stock via an ID value, and has zero to many records for each Stock item.

```
SELECT Q1.id, Q1.Total1, Q2.Total2
, Q1.Total1 - COALESCE(Q2.Total2,0) as Outstanding
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) as Total1
        FROM Stock GROUP BY id
) as Q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, SUM(Amount) as Total2
        FROM Sold GROUP BY id
) as Q2
  ON Q2.id = Q1.id
```

Note that simply formatting your SQL into a clean way forces you to break it into logical parts and will often reveal exactly what is wrong with the query.
The example above also handles correctly the cases where there is not match in the Sold table.

Cheers,
Daniel

(Code Assumptions)

```
DROP TABLE Stock
CREATE TABLE Stock (
 id integer
, amount decimal(10,2)
) 

INSERT INTO Stock (id, amount ) VALUES ( 1, 10.1);
INSERT INTO Stock (id, amount ) VALUES ( 2, 20.2);
INSERT INTO Stock (id, amount ) VALUES ( 3, 30.3);

SELECT * FROM STOCK

DROP TABLE Sold
CREATE TABLE Sold (
 id integer
, amount decimal(10,2)
) 

INSERT INTO Sold (id, amount ) VALUES ( 1, 1.1);
INSERT INTO Sold (id, amount ) VALUES ( 1, 2.2);
INSERT INTO Sold (id, amount ) VALUES ( 1, 3.3);
INSERT INTO Sold (id, amount ) VALUES ( 2, 2.22);

SELECT * FROM Sold


SELECT Q1.id, Q1.Total1, Q2.Total2
, Q1.Total1 - COALESCE(Q2.Total2,0) as Outstanding
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, SUM(amount) as Total1
    FROM Stock GROUP BY id
) as Q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(Amount) as Total2
    FROM Sold GROUP BY id
) as Q2
  ON Q2.id = Q1.id
```

Results:

```
id  Total1  Total2  Outstanding
1   10.10   6.60    3.50
2   20.20   2.22    17.98
3   30.30       30.30
```

Answer (score 0):

**REVISION**

It sounds like you want the total amount of stock you have as one count for each different stock. Then you want how much stock you have left for each stock based on what has been sold. Correct?

If so check this out:

```
select stock, sum(a.x) as sharesBeforeSale, (sum(a.x) - sum(b.y)) as sharesAfterSale 
FROM db.table1 a, db.table2 b  
WHERE a.UNIQUEID = b.UNIQUEID AND b.y IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.UNIQUEID;
```

Does that accomplish what you are looking to do?

```
stock       sharesBeforeSale       sharesAfterSale
duk         100                    25
orc         101                    101
yrc          54                    41
```

Enjoy!

> Sample tables

```
db.table1 (stock owned):
UNIQUEID    x   stock
1         100     duk
2         101     orc
3          54     yrc

db.table2 (stock sold):
UNIQUEID    y   
1          75   
2           0     
3          13
```

Comment: i didn't ask how to join two tables. they are aleady joined, but i need the sum on subsets of the joins

Comment: I saw that. In your example you are not using a 'where' in your join. To get the sum of subsets of the join (so only results where the unique id is in both tables) you will need a where clause which will join the tables on the unique id. Group by will give you more than one result usually for each unique id. Maybe give more of an example please?

Comment: this is about what i have, the problem is, the sum of b.y can not be calculated by a.UNIQUEID, but by b.SOMETHING. a.x however needs to be grouped by a.x to calculate the sum correctly