# How to prepare result based on certain conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord

I have got following 3 models(order, insurance, donation).

```
 #order.rb
has_one :donations 
has_one :insurances

 #insurance.rb
belongs_to :order

 #donation.rb
belongs_to :order
```

Now my respective tables hold following data :

```
 #Order
id customer_id  delivery_status  price 
1    10          true            50
2    10          true            60
3    10          false           70
4    10          false           80
5    10          true            90
6    10          true            10

 #insurance
id token  order_id
1   ABC     3

 #donation
id  amount order_id
1      10    4
```

Now, I need to prepare final report for each customer with attributes like their id, total price of delivered items, total price of undelivered items, amount(from donation), token(from insurance).

In final result I need something like this:

```
customer_id  total_price_of_delivered  total_price_of_undelivered amount token
1             50+60+90+10=250                  150            10    ABC
2             xxxx                             xxx           XXX      XXX
```

Currently I am trying with following code base:

```
result = Order.includes(:insurance, :donation)

delivered_items_price = 0 
undelivered_items_price = 0 
result.each do |order| 
 customer_id = order.customer_id 
  # will loop through all orders based on conditions. 
  #then put the fetched result in an array of hash. 
end
```

Do we have any better alternative/solution for this problem ?

Comment: I would first group `order`s based on delivery status, then get a sum of price and then join with the other tables. Of course all of it in SQL (Using ActiveRecord or Arel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it the [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) way. I'm gonna give you an outline of what has to be done instead of runnable code with code snippets from Arel's documentation.

1. We are going to use `arel_table`s to create our query. For a model called for example `Order`, getting the Arel table is as easy as `orders = Order.arel_table`
2. Getting sum of a column combined with grouping is like `orders.project(orders[:price].count).group(users[:delivery_status])`. Note that you need to first group by `customer` and then by `delivery_status`.
3. Since we need to have multiple sums in our end result you need to make use of [Common Table Expressions(CTE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression). Take a look at docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248737/2295964) for more info on this.
4. At the end you will join the result with other tables. E.g. `orders.join(insurances).on(YOUR_CONDITIONS)`