# SubQuery Aggregates in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to avoid using straight up SQL in my Rails app, but need to do a quite large version of this:

```
SELECT ds.product_id,
  ( SELECT SUM(units) FROM daily_sales WHERE (date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-08') AND service_type = 1 ) as wk1,
  ( SELECT SUM(units) FROM daily_sales WHERE (date BETWEEN '2015-01-09' AND '2015-01-16') AND service_type = 1 ) as wk2
FROM daily_sales as ds group by ds.product_id
```

I'm sure it can be done, but i'm struggling to write this as an active record statement. Can anyone help?

Comment: Rewrite your sql query as `SELECT ds.product_id,
     Sum(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-08' AND service_type = 1 THEN units
     ELSE 0 END) AS wk1,
     Sum(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2015-01-09' AND '2015-01-16' AND service_type = 1 THEN units
     ELSE 0 END) AS wk2,
 FROM   daily_sales AS ds
 GROUP  BY ds.product_id 
`

Answer (score 1):

If you must do this in a single query, you'll need to write some SQL for the CASE statements. The following is what you need:

```
ranges = [ # ordered array of all your date-ranges
  Date.new(2015, 1, 1)..Date.new(2015, 1, 8),
  Date.new(2015, 1, 9)..Date.new(2015, 1, 16)
]

overall_range = (ranges.first.min)..(ranges.last.max)

grouping_sub_str = \
  ranges.map.with_index do |range, i|
    "WHEN (date BETWEEN '#{range.min}' AND '#{range.max}') THEN 'week#{i}'"
  end.join(' ')

grouping_condition = "CASE #{grouping_sub_str} END"
grouping_columns = ['product_id', grouping_condition]

DailySale.where(date: overall_range).group(grouping_columns).sum(:units)
```

That will produce a hash with array keys and numeric values. A key will be of the form `[product_id, 'week1']` and the value will be the corresponding sum of `units` for that week.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of close to the way it currently works but i'm trying to move away from it as it's not efficient enough as I have millions of lines in my DB. I'm also going to be grabbing something like 36 aggregate metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your SQL to the following and try converting it..

```
SELECT ds.product_id,
, SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-08' AND service_type = 1
    THEN units
    END) WK1
    , SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2015-01-09' AND '2015-01-16' AND service_type = 1
    THEN units
    END) WK2 
FROM daily_sales as ds 
group by ds.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll definitely consider this if I can find a more Rails like way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Every rail developer sooner or later hits his/her head against the walls of [Active Record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) just to find the solution in [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

Arel gives you the flexibility that you need in creating your query without using loops, etc. I am not going to give runnable code rather some hints how to do it yourself:

1. We are going to use `arel_table`s to create our query. For a model called for example `Product`, getting the Arel table is as easy as `products = Product.arel_table`
2. Getting sum of a column is like `daily_sales.project(daily_sales[:units].count).where(daily_sales[:date].gt(BEGIN_DATE).where(daily_sales[:date].lt(END_DATE)`. You can chain as many `where`s as you want and it will be translated into SQL `AND`s.
3. Since we need to have multiple sums in our end result you need to make use of [Common Table Expressions(CTE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression). Take a look at docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248737/2295964) for more info on this.
4. You can use those CTEs from step 3 in combination with `group` and you are done!

Comment: thanks for this. I've seen references to Arel a few times but have never actually delved into it. I'll definitely take some time to get familiar with it.

Comment: It's totally worth it since it's much faster to let SQL do the calculation than ruby!